# Creating GCE Kube cluster v1.2 via API fails

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I tried creating a new kube cluster via googleapis with oAuth authentication. But I am getting an error that 
**"HTTP Load Balancing requires the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute' scope."**. 
I came to know that google has updated the kube version to **1.2** the previous night in their console (until which I was able to create cluster using same method in **v1.0**)
I tried creating one via API explorer using google's oAuth, but it failed with same error.
I think the authscope has been updated, but I could not find the new authscope in any of '**google cloud platform container engine doc**' or '**kubernetes latest release doc**'. Can someone please help me in identifying the new authscope?[image: Accessing via google cloud platform - screen shot]
[image: Request and response - screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message was due to an error on our part while rolling out support for Kubernetes 1.2 in Google Container Engine. We've fixed the issues, and you can now create a container cluster using the api explorer. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is referring to the scopes provided in the NodeConfig of the CreateCluster request. In 1.2, the "compute" scope is required to run the HTTP Load Balancer addon:

```
"nodeConfig": {
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute"
  ]
}
```

If you don't want to add the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute` scope to your nodes, you can also disable HTTP Load Balancing by passing in an AddonsConfig that disables it:

```
"addonsConfig": {
  "httpLoadBalancing": {
    "disabled": true
  }
}
```